# Is it necessary to create two-way route for transit gateway on AWS?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

For multiple aws accounts, we want to make network communicable from A to B.

Use [transit gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/transit-gateway) can allow 2 different vpcs access each other.

If want to access from A to B only, in account A, made a [route](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html) to account B, is it also necessary to create a route from B to A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each VPC / route table needs a route to the transit gateway. All routing is controlled by the route tables in AWS.

If you need shared internet egress you can have a VPC with a tgw endpoint and NAT gateway in a private subnet, routing to an internet gateway which is effectively in a public subnet. Then you can use AWS network firewall or similar to restrict egress.